# Python and dygraph - no len

Tags: javascript, python, dygraphs

I am completely new to Python and dygraph but trying to reproduce the first example mentioned here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dyplot

I downloaded the package and copied it into the Anaconda directory, so it is acually recognized by my IPython code. However, the copied code throws an error:

```
import pandas as pd
from dyplot.dygraphs import Dygraphs
dg = Dygraphs(a.index, "index")
dg.plot(series="a", mseries=a)
dg.plot(series="b", mseries=b)
dg.plot(series="c", mseries=c,lseries=lc, hseries=hc)
dg.set_options(title="Test")
div = dg.savefig(csv_file="tutorial.csv", html_file="tutorial1.html")
```

[image]

Does anybody has a clue about this problem?
I use Python 3.4

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a, b, c, lc and hc as pandas series. Insert these lines after the last import.

```
a = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10])
b = pd.Series([1,3,5,9,2,8,5,5,15])
lc= pd.Series([1,3,4,5,6,7,9,3,2])
c = pd.Series([2,4,5,7,8,8,9,4,3])
hc= pd.Series([3,5,7,7,9,11,9,5,8])
```

Check http://dyplot.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials.html